# Python group by row and string topics to create new columns with binary value

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, pivot-table

I have a large csv where each row is a separate school course, each of which is tagged with one or more topics, like so:

| school name | department | course name | topics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | X | fruit; vegetable |
| A | A1 | Y | fruit; grains |
| B | B1 | Z | fruit; vegetable; sweets |
| C | C1 | XX | fruit; poultry |

I need to calculate the presence of each topic for each course. Each topic needs to be appended as its own column, with each row coded as either a 0 or 1 depending on whether the topic is present in the course. There are 49 topics in total, so I need to add 49 rows to the table.

There are 4000 rows, many of which are repeats of the same course name, so those need to be grouped as well. For example, if one instance of course name X has topics "fruit", "vegetable" but another instance of the same course has topics "fruit", "grains", the binary values for column "fruit" should be 1, "vegetable" should be 1, and "grains" should be 1, while the rest of the topic columns are coded as 0.

The output should look something like this:

| school name | department | course name | fruit | vegetable | grains | sweets | poultry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | X | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | A1 | Y | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| B | B1 | Z | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| C | C1 | XX | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I have the solution if the topics were numeric, but I'm not sure how to go about this given that the topics are string values.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['topics.csv']))

x = df.pop("Final Topic").str.split(r"\s*;\s*").explode()
x = pd.crosstab(x.index, x).add_prefix("topic ")
df = pd.concat([df, x], axis=1)
```

This code just registers everything as 0, like so:

| school name | department | course name | fruit | vegetable | grains | sweets | poultry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | X | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | A1 | Y | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | B1 | Z | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | C1 | XX | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I haven't used python for a long time, so I forget how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# form a list by splitting the topics
df['topics']=df['topics'].str.split(';')

# explode to turn list values into rows
df=df.explode('topics')

# use get_dummies to get indicators for the value
# and then groupby and sum

out=(pd.concat([df ,                            # merge the DF with 
                pd.get_dummies(df['topics'])],  # create indicator columns
               axis=1)                          # along rows
     .drop(columns='topics')                    # drop indicator value col
     .groupby(['school name','department', 'course name'], as_index=False) #group
     .sum())
out
```

```
school name     department  course name     grains  poultry     sweets  vegetable   fruit
0        A              A1            X          0        0          0          1       1
1        A              A1            Y          1        0          0          0       1
2        B              B1            Z          0        0          1          1       1
3        C              C1            XX         0        1          0          0       1
```